# Could not read from remote repository using ssh key in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visusal Studio Code. I am trying to connect to my repo and I can easily push changes but when I do pull, I get the following message.

```
git fetch
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can anyone guide me how?

Comment: Got the exact same issue, nothing that I have found seems to work. A solution would be nice.

Comment: @reaper_unique, I forgot I submitted this issue here. Now I remember lol. As what I recall we manage to fix this by creating a repo again and added me back.